# Importing scss file to another

Tags: reactjs, sass

`index.js` file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './index.scss';

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div>test</div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

`index.scss` file:

```
@import 'styles/_styles.scss';
// @import '../../../../styles/_styles.scss';
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: styles/_styles.scss.
```

So if I comment first line in `index.scss` and uncomment second it will work just fine but problem is what path is too long and looks ugly, I also need to import it to another file in different directories which will only make path longer.

Comment: you can provide absolute path, or move scss file to the same directory.

Comment: Have you tried `@import 'styles/styles.scss'; without underscore? Afaik, that's how scss imports partials.

Comment: @AmitRai I wouldn't be asking a question here if I could do that, `_styles.scss` have imports from colors, vars, mixins and etc.

Comment: @Swan, you can full path from src directory, may it look fine

Comment: @Clarity same error

Comment: @AmitRai `styles` folder is in `src` dir :/